# problems with TriScatteredInterp

Tags: matlab

I have two sets of scattered data x y z and x2 y2 z2

The following code should produce two overlapping surface plots

```
F = TriScatteredInterp(x,y,z);
z2i=F(x2,y2);

tri = delaunay(x,y);

plot = trisurf(tri,x2,y2,z2,'edgeColor','blue','FaceColor','blue','FaceAlpha',.5);
hold on
trisurf(tri,x2,y2,z2i,'edgeColor','red','FaceColor','red','FaceAlpha',.5);
```

Somehow, the two plots are not even close.  Does anyone know how this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are moving from first set of x and y to the second set x2 and y2, calculate triangulation based on x2 and y2.

```
tri = delaunay(x2,y2);
```

Don't forget `hold off` at the end.